# Extract ID and Date from file name

Tags: python, pandas

I have this filename as source of data of my dataframe

```
file_name = 2900-ABC Project-20210525-Data 1
```

and I want to get the 4 first number as a new column called `ID` and also the date in the filename as the new column called event_date.

The expected results would be:

```
id     event_date
2900   2021-05-25
```

How can I get it in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.extract` and `str.replace`:

```py
df["id"] = df["file_name"].str.extract(r'^(\d+)')
df["event_date"] = df["file_name"].str.replace(r'^.*-(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})-.*$', r'\1-\2-\3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Barring regular expressions, this can be done with [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

file_name = '2900-ABC Project-20210525-Data 1'

file_split = file_name.split('-')
id_value = int(file_split[0])
date = dt.datetime.strptime(file_split[2], '%Y%m%d').date()

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [id_value], 'event_date': [date]})
```